# Integration test execution should wait until server is ready

Tags: maven, selenium, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have written Selenium tests which should be executed during the build process of an web application. I am using the maven-failsafe-plugin to execute the integration tests and the tomcat7-maven-plugin to start up a tomcat server in the pre-integration-test phase and after the execution of the tests it gets stopped in the post-integration-test phase. This works fine.

The problem is that the tomcat server is caching some data when started up to improve the search speed. Some of my tests rely on that data, so the integration tests should wait for the server to finish caching the data.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a process bar to show the loading progress. Once the loading is complete the process bar is not rendered anymore and the data table will be rendered. In this way I can add to the tests which depend on the data table to be loaded this line of code:

```
longWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("dataTablePanel")));
```

Additionally I am using `org.junit.runners.Suite` as a runner so that I can specify the order of how my test classes will be executed. Thereby I can execute the test which do not rely on the data first and then the ones which need it. To ensure that the data is present and I don't need to check that in every test case, I have created a test class which will only check the presence of the data and will be executed before all test cases which depend on the data.